# Passing a JS array from a Servlet to jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets

I am creating following string response in jsp

[[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]],[[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]]

and getting this response in jquery ,

but i am getting it as 1D array,  i need array to be like that only

Comment: it's setting it as ,  var a = "[[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]],[[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]]";

Answer (score 0):

Make the response json encoded and then use

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
```

Comment: i don't want to use JSON because i don't believe on IE

Comment: it's setting response in jquery as string like  var a = "arr1 = [[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]],[[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]]"  but i want it to be array